# While embeding an Apache Superset dashboard in a webpage receiving error

Tags: apache-superset

I have successfully embedded the dashboard on webpage, but when i opened the link receiving "MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'customer_id' in 'where clause'")" error.
After checking logs i can see it is querying the my database queries with respect to customer_id.
I am not getting why it is asking "customer_id".

Answer (score 0):

You got guest token by sending this json

```json
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "id": "dashboard_id",
      "type": "dashboard"
    }
  ],
  "rls": [
    {
      "clause": "customer_id = 1" // here you wrote customer_id
    } 
  ],
  "user": {
    "first_name": "firstname",
    "last_name": "lastname",
    "username": "username"
  }
}
```

But you should get guest token by sending rls field as an empty array

```json
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "id": "dashboard_id",
      "type": "dashboard"
    }
  ],
  "rls": [],
  "user": {
    "first_name": "firstname",
    "last_name": "lastname",
    "username": "username"
  }
}
```